# На странице тревог слетел перевод строки "flags raised" (и не только)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, история-тревог

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на страницах отдельных фильтров теперь какая-то катавасия. К примеру, на странице [отклонённых тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current?group=1&status=3).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нормальный перевод всё равно пока нельзя сделать. [Уже полтора года как отложено.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ   (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующий [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/12149):

> $status$ $group$ тревоги, установленные участником $user$

Нормальный перевод всё равно пока не сделать из-за текущей реализации формирования строк: [Impossible to localize flag summary page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911)

Comment: Ещё забыли https://ru.traducir.win/string/12150 и https://ru.traducir.win/string/12144. Добавил.

Comment: @Suvitruf акцептнул

Comment: Хм, а разрабы даже переименовать `$status$` в какое-нибудь `$flags_title_status$` не могут / не хотят?

Comment: @andreymal это чем-то отличается от того, что описано на MSE?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ конечно, то что я предлагаю очень сильно отличается от «full sentences should be used» — это комбинаторный взрыв, а мой вариант нет

Comment: @andreymal не очень понимаю ваш вариант в таком случае и как он решит обозначенную проблему.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ `$flags_title_status$ $flags_title_group$ flags` же. В таком случае нужно сделать не N×N вариантов перевода, как при «full sentences», а всего лишь N+N — отдельно для статуса и отдельно для группы

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это, конечно, тоже не самый качественный вариант, но по крайней мере упомянутого на метамете комбинаторного взрыва уже не будет, а статусы тревог не смешаются с другими статусами, как сделано сейчас